# C# How to move element on WFA in direction of mouse click controlling speed with timer

Tags: c#, timer

I have been trying to solve this problem for a really long time.

Is it possible to move button on Windows Forms application in C# in direction of click event, but controlling the speed of the movement by a timer function?

Here is my code. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
namespace juriKlik
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int otkucaj = 1;
            MrdajDugme(otkucaj);
        }

        private void MrdajDugme(int otkucaj)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text);
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(label7.Text);
            int d = Convert.ToInt32(label8.Text);

            Point p = new Point(c + otkucaj, d);
            button1.Location = p;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = Convert.ToString(e.X);
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(e.Y);
            label7.Text = Convert.ToString(button1.Location.X);
            label8.Text = Convert.ToString(button1.Location.Y);

            int a = e.X;
            int b = e.Y;
            int c = button1.Location.X;
            int d = button1.Location.Y;

            if(a > c)
            {
                timer1.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for editing! Would it be possible for you to take a look at the code and see what am I doing wrong? I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: I had a look at it - but I am not too "fluent" in Windows Forms stuff anymore... I'm sure someone will be able to help you